# Delphi2009, IBX and firebird with utf8 give a division by zero error

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-2009, firebird2.5

I'm using Delphi 2009 with firebird 2.5 and with IBXpres I'm getting the "Division by zero" error.

The firebird's DB is created with charset `UTF8` and collation `UNICODE_CI`.

I already modified the IBSQL.pas, recompiled the ibxpress120.bpl and, at design time, everything works. [This is the link with the fix](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=69856)

The problem is that I still get the error at runtime when I oen my dataset:

```
MyIBDataSet.Open;
```

If I use `UNICODE_FSS` for the charset, everything works, but I can not set the collation to "case insensitive"

Any workaround I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeff Overcash states in the QC report you linked, IBX doen't support Firebird. So the best solution is not to try to find a workaround for it but to switch to some other component set which officially supports FB. I have been using [UIB (Unified Interbase)](http://www.progdigy.com/) but there is other solutions available as well.

Comment: I know that, my problem is that it's a big software, so before evaluating the migration, I was looking for a temporary solution. I will look at the component you suggest. Thanks

Comment: @Iridio How this could be a big software if you are encountering this error? are you migrating from a earlier version of Delphi or Firebird? or what are you changing in the first place that breaks your app?

Comment: The request is to migrate to a newer version of Firebird with case insensitive collation. I guees I have no options, but to implement a new set of lib